# Prismic integration with Gatsby causing window to be undefined in build

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm using 'gatsby-source-prismic-graphql' to integrate a Prismic repository with an existing Gatsby project, but am finding that the `window` object is undefined when the site is built. The problem is different (though maybe related?) to that caused by Gatsby's SSR when it generates static files during build (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

I'm using safety checks (i.e. `typeof window !== 'undefined' ...`) recommended by Gatsby, and have no issues building, but the problem persists - namely, eventListener's that work fine locally are unresponsive in the build itself. The window object is properly defined in builds I've tested prior to integrating `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql` in gatsby-config.js, but is undefined as soon as I integrate it.

Any ideas? I've reproduced the behaviour across multiple new projects (always reoccurring as soon as 'gatsby-source-prismic-graphql'/a Prismic repo is added in config), and am stumped

Comment: You may want to file an issue on the [gatsby-source-prismic-graphql project's Github](https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql). At a glance it appears that the plugin does modify `window`, so it's likely a bug there and not necessarily something that is well suited to StackOverflow helping with.